# The Index view does not receive the list partial from the ajax call made from Searchbox partial?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i have the following partial view for the the `_searchbox` partial

```
@model ecomm2.Models.MainSearchBoxViewModel


<div id="search-box-wrapper" style="text-align:center">
<div id="search-box-div" style="display:inline-block">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetResults", "Partials", 
    new AjaxOptions { 
        HttpMethod="get", 
        InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace, 
        OnSuccess="updateMainResultsDiv", 
        UpdateTargetId="divMainResultsList"}))
{    
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <fieldset>
                <label>Search: </label>
            </fieldset>
            </td>
            <td>
        <fieldset>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProdCatId, Model.MainSearchDDLCollection, new { style="width:200px;"})
        </fieldset>
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>            
    <td>
        <fieldset>
            <input type="text" name="SearchText" style="width:400px"/>
        </fieldset>
    </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Search" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
}
    </div>
</div>
<br />
```

then i have added this `_SearchBox` partial view to the layout so each page gets a *searchbox with a drown category list to filter the search*.

note: _searchbox partial  is called by Another action in the "`Partials`" controller and works fine.

the action method "`GetResults`" is in the "`Partials`" controller and this is the method that is called by **ajax** from `_SearchBox` partial

```
[AjaxOnly]
public ActionResult GetResults(int ProdCatId, string SearchText) 
{
    var Products = db.mt_Products
        .Where(e => e.SearchString.Contains(SearchText) & e.ProdCatId == ProdCatId)
        .Select(e => new HomeSearchResultsViewModel 
        { 
            Id=e.Id, 
            ProdCode=e.ProdCode.Trim(), 
            ProductLineName= e.mt_Brands.BrandName.Trim() +" "+ e.ProdName.Trim(), 
            ListPrice=e.ListPrice, 
            ProdImage=e.ProdImg, 
            StockCount=e.Stock, 
            BrandName=e.mt_Brands.BrandName.Trim(), 
            CategoryName=e.mt_ProductCategories.CatName.Trim()
        }).ToList();

    return PartialView("_SearchResults", Products);

}
```

then i have the following code in `Index` view of the `Home` controller

```
@model IEnumerable<ecomm2.Models.HomeSearchResultsViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Welcome Admin,</h2>

<p>

</p>

<div id="divMainResultsList">
@Html.Partial("_SearchResultsList", Model)
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateMainResultsDiv() {
        $('#divMainResultsList').html()
    }
</script>
```

when i passed a value to the search box and performed a search, it showed that search values were received by the action method `GetResults` and LINQ generates results but result were not placed on div area. Is this div placed on right spot?

it seems a bit complicated to post all and [here is the video](https://youtu.be/Mfyl1DKNmdU)

Comment: Your calling an ajax method that returns a partial view and inserts into a div with `id="divMainResultsList"` and then immediately calling function `updateMainResultsDiv()` which clears it (remove the `OnSuccess` option from your `Ajax.BeginForm()`) although I think you potentially have some other errors here as well

Comment: @StephenMuecke isn't teh function updateMainResultsDiv() responsible for placing the returned partial on the div area? So basically the new results will clear the old partial call?

Comment: No. Thats what your `Ajax.BeginForm()` is doing - its calls the function and then inserts the partial it returns in the element specified by `UpdateTargetId`. Remove the `updateMainResultsDiv()` script and the `OnSuccess` option - buts that's not you only problem - give me a bit more time

Comment: @StephenMuecke okay! : )